# Firebase Storage's ref.write(toFile) shows An unknown error occurred, please check the server response

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, filesystems, firebase-storage

I am trying to download a video from Firebase Storage and store it locally to my device like below and I am getting an error `An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.`

I have no clue what I am doing wrong when this looks similar to Firebase's [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files)

Here is my code

```
    let videoRef = storage.reference(forURL: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bolar-ea96c.appspot.com/o/ChatVideos%2FL1f4FHqRlMYRJvUxP31c7FwI7Wj2:eUuKNzOByBcjQbwAZXmzY4iPj952%2F98E983A0-0E91-4DAB-BF50-16C1AF2E1894%2FIMG_4776.MOV?alt=media&token=1867f82e-e24e-43b9-99ad-5d21163f1469")
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.downloadsDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    let docURL = URL(string: documentsDirectory)!
    let localUrl = docURL.appendingPathComponent("\(self.chatRoomId)/\(chatId)")
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: localUrl.absoluteString) {
        do {
            let downloadTask = videoRef.write(toFile: localUrl) { (videoLocalUrl, error) in //download the video from Storage and store it to a localUrl
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error getting video URL from \(videoUrl.absoluteString) \nWith error = \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return //MARK: Getting error here
                }
                chat.video?.videoLocalUrl = videoLocalUrl!
                tempChats.append(chat)
                print("Successfully downloaded video from \(videoLocalUrl!)")
            }
            downloadTask.observe(.success) { (snapshot) in
                print("Completed \(snapshot)")
            }
        }
    }
```